# Paypal sandbox, where can i find CertKey

Tags: paypal-sandbox

In Project "merchantsample"--Configuration class, there is "acct2.CertKey" attribute for Certificate credential.

I want to replace the value with myself, but I cannot find the value in my sandbox account.
Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following in your SandBox account:

1. Click Profile
2. Click Selling Tools
3. Click Request API Credentials
4. Choose the radio tab API Certificate
5. Click Agree and Submit

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But after that, I only get API username:********** and API password:*******. However I don't find the information about Cert Key.